# I am using this code for sending the image file and text file ..i already build java path for than still it showing error

Tags: php, android

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mobitracktechnologies.in/imagefiles.php");
StringBody data = new StringBody(textTosend, Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8));
MultiPartEntity entity = new MultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(filePath, "image/jpeg");
entity.addPart("file", cbFile);
entity.addPart("text", data);
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse WSresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: line no 4 error is....Cannot instantiate the type MultiPartEntity

Comment: line no 6,7,8 error is...The method addPart(String, StringBody) is undefined for the type MultiPartEntity

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: And what are errors ?

Comment: error i mention in comment

Comment: @user2846110 check import statement for MultiPartEntity.

Comment: @user2846110 do you have the jars in your libs folder?

Comment: ya i have  already mention over there

Comment: @user2846110 it should be `MultipartEntity` not `MultiPartEntity`

Answer (score 1):

Use the below

```
 MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

and import

```
 import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
 import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer but still problem not resolve same isue is still now

Comment: @user2846110 do you have the required jars in your projects libs folder?

Comment: ya i have all four Jar files in my folder

Comment: @user2846110 where do you have these statements. It should work and show your import statements

Comment: in build path i mention

Comment: @user2846110 show your import statements and you should add jars to your projects libs folder. it will be added to build path automatically. you are doing it wrong hence the error

Comment: ya i did same thing i added in Libs folder only

Comment: @user2846110 show us your import statements. I see no reason for the error if you have added the jars folder. post your full code

Comment: in this code only there is a problem rest all is working fine

Comment: @user2846110 why not post your import statements and your full code. coz i see nothing wrong with your code except for the change i suggested

Comment: @Raghunandan just want to delete my question